# ARKit just showing blue screen in Unity, not using camera?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, camera, arkit, xcode9-beta

Ok I have no idea what is going on here, cant find any solutions anywhere. Here is what I happens when I try to run this ARKit Unity demo (or any AR demo for that matter) https://github.com/FusedVR/PetAR built to my iPhone -

[image]

The UI shows up, but where the camera capture is supposed to be occurring, I just have a blue screen. This is not what happens on their demo video online and it seems no one else has this problem.

I am on Unity 5.6.6, however I was on 2017 before and that did not work either. I made sure I had some text written in my "Camera description" field so the iPhone would allow camera access, and I am out of solutions at this point.

How can I get ARKit to work in Unity deployed to iOS? What am I doing wrong here?

I have the Unity build deploying via Xcode 9 the most recent beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain hardware and software requirements in order to run ARKit-based applications.

https://developer.apple.com/arkit/

> **High Performance Hardware and Rendering Optimizations**
>
> ARKit runs on the Apple A9 and A10 processors.

Practically, you need an iPhone 6s or newer.

> **Introducing ARKit**
>
> iOS 11 introduces ARKit, a new framework

iOS 11 is also required.

Comment: I have an iPhone 7. Could it be that I'm not on the latest latest iOS?

Comment: Hold on - I don't have the iOS 11 beta. Do I actually need that to run arkit from unity? I don't want to get on iOS 11 because I won't be able to run apps from Xcode 8

Comment: @skyguy, yes you need iOS 11 as well - updated the answer.